# Позиционирование элементов с помощью flexbox html/css

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox, позиционирование

Пытаюсь разобраться со свойством flexbox.

У меня постоянно проблема в размерах: 1ый блок идет нормально, а остальные как-то кривовато; я хочу, чтобы второй и третий блок были в столбик и по всей ширине, - как на макете, - но 1ый блок не дает этого сделать, не знаю почему, подскажите.

Прикрепляю свой код и картинки. Пожалуйста, объясните мне, - начинающему верстальщику, - как это работает и что мне нужно подправить?

```css
.block_2 .about_us {
    padding: 1.6% 0 1.6% 0;
}
.block_2 .about_us h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.block_2 .content p {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 37.1%;
}
.block_2 .text p {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    
}


.block_2 .content {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.block_2 .image  {
    width: 478px;
    padding: 0 1.6% 0 12%;
    
}
.block_2 .all_text  {
    flex-direction: column;
    
}



/* Еще пробовал как-то так сделать, но тоже не вышло 

пример 2

.block_2 img {
    width: 37.3%;
    height: 9.5%;
    margin: 0 1.6% 0 12%;
}

.block_2 .content p {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 37.1%;
}
.block_2 .text {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
.block_2 .text img {
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
}
.block_2 .text p {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="block_2">
            <div class="about_us">       
                <h1>ABOUT US</h1>
            </div>
            
            <div class="content">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="img/block_2_youtube.png" alt="Youtube">
                </div>
                <div class="all_text">
                    <div class="paragraph">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce libero dui, pharetra vitae tempus id, interdum in elit. Fusce cursus interdum auctor. Proin et aliquam tellus, vel egestas sapien. </p>
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                        <p>
                            <img src="img/block_2_num1.png" alt="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.<br>
                            <img src="img/block_2_num2.png" alt="">Deleniti fuga minus molestias omnis perferendis voluptatem.<br>
                            <img src="img/block_2_num3.png" alt="">Laboriosam maiores nisi nulla recusandae repellendus vero.<br>
                            <img src="img/block_2_num4.png" alt="">Corporis, eos impedit pariatur quaerat quod reprehenderit?<br>
                            <img src="img/block_2_num5.png" alt="">Dolore fuga illo iure quas quisquam voluptates.<br>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
```

Картинки которые могут понадобится:

[image: img/block_2_num1.png]

[image: img/block_2_num2.png]

[image: img/block_2_num3.png]

[image: img/block_2_num4.png]

[image: img/block_2_num5.png]

[image: img/block_2_youtube.png]

[image: Макет блока]

Comment: Как видете по коду элементы которые находятся во втором и третьем блоке как бы уменьшаются, хотя место на экране еще очень много, пробовал много способов решить но ничего не выходит. Подскажите как это исправить, а главное почему так выходит что 1й блок нормально отображается а следующие два как бы сужаются, а не растягиваются по всей странице.

Comment: Исходя из примера все работает, текст в блоке `paragraph` не на всю ширину, поскольку у тега `p` указана ширина в `37%`

Comment: По макету если посчитать будет показывать 37% . Но когда я добавляю селектору .paragraph {width: 37%;} текст еще становится меньше. Как бы сужается. Я думал нужно добавить обертке .content { width: 100%; } . Но все равно не работает так как на макете. Если вы не заняты вечером, могли бы вы мне помочь разобраться с этим в discord'e? Я бы вам тогда скинул psd макет и объяснил по демонстрации экрана что не получается конкретно. Если не можете, то все равно большое спасибо за помощь и за быстрый ответ. Мой дискорд: Lisenok#3858

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите у тега `p` ширину в `37%`, и задайте блокам `image` и `all_text` свойство `flex: 1;`.

```css
*  {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.block_2 .about_us {
    padding: 1.6% 0 1.6% 0;
}
.block_2 .about_us h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.block_2 .content p {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.block_2 .text p {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    
}


.block_2 .content {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.block_2 .image,
.block_2 .all_text  {
    flex: 1;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="block_2">
            <div class="about_us">       
                <h1>ABOUT US</h1>
            </div>
            
            <div class="content">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/720x480?text=YouTube" alt="Youtube">
                </div>
                <div class="all_text">
                    <div class="paragraph">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce libero dui, pharetra vitae tempus id, interdum in elit. Fusce cursus interdum auctor. Proin et aliquam tellus, vel egestas sapien. </p>
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                        <p>
                            <img src="img/block_2_num1.png" alt="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.<br>
                            <img src="img/block_2_num2.png" alt="">Deleniti fuga minus molestias omnis perferendis voluptatem.<br>
                            <img src="img/block_2_num3.png" alt="">Laboriosam maiores nisi nulla recusandae repellendus vero.<br>
                            <img src="img/block_2_num4.png" alt="">Corporis, eos impedit pariatur quaerat quod reprehenderit?<br>
                            <img src="img/block_2_num5.png" alt="">Dolore fuga illo iure quas quisquam voluptates.<br>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот мой варинат решения.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,400,600");
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }

.main-part {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; }

.about-us-title {
  width: 80%;
  height: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  margin: 3vw 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000; }
.about-us-title > span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0.6em;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 3vw;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase; }

.about-us {
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; }

.au-left {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start; }
.au-left > img {
  width: 90%; }

.au-right {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start; }

.au-right-description {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  font-size: .9vw;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  font-weight: 100; }

.aur-list-item {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-bottom: .7vw; }
.aur-list-item > img {
  width: 3%;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: .7em; }
.aur-list-item > span {
  width: 95%;
  display: block;
  font-size: .9vw; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div style="height: 80%; width: 100%; background-color: yellow;">Можно убрать</div>

<div class="main-part">
    <div class="about-us-title"><span>About Us</span></div>
    <div class="about-us">
        <div class="au-left">
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLJup.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="au-right">
            <span class="au-right-description">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A consequatur doloribus eveniet fugiat necessitatibus non veniam. Alias, aut doloribus excepturi magnam quas ratione sunt tempore. Commodi cum, enim est harum itaque iusto, nam obcaecati.
            </span>
            <div class="aur-list-item">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqUoQ.png" alt="">
                <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque laudantium minima possimus!</span>
            </div>
            <div class="aur-list-item">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNBGR.png" alt="">
                <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque laudantium minima possimus!</span>
            </div>
            <div class="aur-list-item">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2b0V.png" alt="">
                <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque laudantium minima possimus!</span>
            </div>
            <div class="aur-list-item">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qursy.png" alt="">
                <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque laudantium minima possimus!</span>
            </div>
            <div class="aur-list-item">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcD2D.png" alt="">
                <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque laudantium minima possimus!</span>
            </div>



        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="height: 80%; width: 100%; background-color: yellow;">Можно убрать</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Если используешь `scss`:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,400,600');

html, body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main-part{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;

  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.about-us-title {
  width: 80%;
  height: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;

  margin: 3vw 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;

  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;

  & > span{
    display: block;

    position: relative;
    top: 0.6em;
    background-color:  #fff;
    padding: 0 20px;

    font-size: 3vw;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
}

.about-us{
  width: 80%;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.au-left{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;

  & > img{
    width: 90%;
  }
}

.au-right{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.au-right-description{
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2em;

  font-size: .9vw;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.aur-list-item{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;

  margin-bottom: .7vw;

  & > img{
    width: 3%;
    height: auto;

    margin-right: .7em;
  }

  & > span{
    width: 95%;
    display: block;
    font-size: .9vw;
  }
}
```

Comment: Все равно второй и третий блок не по размерам как на макете.  Если не ошибаюсь, то ширина второго и третьего блока 37%

Comment: @Lisenok уточни что ты назваешь вторым и третьим блоком ибо у меня блоков тут ~11

Comment: Я имею введу блоки .paragraph и .text

Comment: @Lisenok у меня таких классов нет.

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за помощь! У меня получилось, не знаю как и что я натыкал, поэтому не спрашивайте, вот готовый вариант!

```css
*  {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.block_2 .about_us {
    padding: 1.6% 0 1.6% 0;
}
.block_2 .about_us:before {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.block_2 .about_us h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.block_2 .content p {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.block_2 .text p {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    
}


.block_2 .content {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.block_2 .image {
    padding: 0 0 0 12%;
}
.block_2 .all_text  {
    max-width: 37.1%;
    padding: 0 0 0 1.6%;
}
.block_2 .all_text .paragraph {
    padding: 0 0 2% 0;
}
.block_2 .all_text .text img {
    padding: 3% 0.6% 0% 0;
}
.block_2 .all_text .text p {
    padding: 0% 0 0.7% 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="block_2">
            <div class="about_us">
                <h1><span>ABOUT US</span></h1>
            </div>  
            <div class="content">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="img/block_2_youtube.png" alt="Youtube">
                </div>
                <div class="all_text">
                    <div class="paragraph">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce libero dui, pharetra vitae tempus id, interdum in elit. Fusce cursus interdum auctor. Proin et aliquam tellus, vel egestas sapien. </p>
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                        <p>
                            <img src="img/block_2_num1.png" alt="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.<br>
                            <img src="img/block_2_num2.png" alt="">Deleniti fuga minus molestias omnis perferendis voluptatem.<br>
                            <img src="img/block_2_num3.png" alt="">Laboriosam maiores nisi nulla recusandae repellendus vero.<br>
                            <img src="img/block_2_num4.png" alt="">Corporis, eos impedit pariatur quaerat quod reprehenderit?<br>
                            <img src="img/block_2_num5.png" alt="">Dolore fuga illo iure quas quisquam voluptates.<br>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Используйте картинки что я скинул в начале, что бы увидеть адекватный код.